# Leather 1.50 German gold mark

Tags: money, numismatics, weimar-republic, german

I have a German 1.50 gold mark that looks to be made of leather. It is about 3/16 of an inch thick. and dyed black. It has many symbols. Please if anyone can tell me about this. It looks to be dated 1923. I can not find another like it anywhere online.  Thank you [image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A real "Gold mark" it is not. Real leather it is, originally intended for shoe soles.

This is [Notgeld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notgeld) or [Ersatz-money](http://www.das-deutsche-notgeld.de), issued after the Great War during the period known as hyperinflation and was one of the last tries to combat the consequences of inflation on a local level. Although most of these were printed on [fancy papers](https://web.archive.org/web/20080917231537/http://einestages.spiegel.de/static/topicalbumbackground/2670/der_schoene_schein.html), intended for local circulation, especially in Thuringia other substrates, like leather went public. One of these was on auction [here](http://www.kiefer.de/auktion_artikel_details.aspx?KatNr=973&Auktion=92) or here:

> [**Notgeld:**](https://lot-tissimo.com/de/i/9078778)
>
> Pößnecker Sohlengeld. 2 Tauschwertscheine aus Rindsleder, Pößneck/Thüringen 27. September 1923. 17 x 10 u. 7,5 x 6 cm.
>   Kuriose Notgeld-Werte aus Sohlenleder. Es erschienen drei Werte (25 u. 50 Goldpfennig sowie 1,50 Goldmark) in einer Auflage von jeweils nur 987 Stück. Vorhanden: 50 Pf. u. 1,50 Mark. - Sehr selten, da wahrscheinlich die meisten Ex. nach Eintritt stabiler Währungsverhältnisse ihrer natürlichen Bestimmung (25 u. 50 Pf. als Absatz, 1,50 Mark als Sohle) zugeführt wurden. Alleinige Fabrikanten waren die beiden Firmen Diesel & Weise (Pößneck) und Potthoff & Kayser in Blankenburg. (Nach: Arno Fickert, Kriegs- u. historische Sammlungen/Seltenheiten-Bilddienst Nr. 7/1938). - Verblasst. "7

From the translation: Very rare specimen, since only 987 of this kind were ever made and most of these were (probably) indeed made into shoe soles after the inflation was brought under control.

In its original condition it probably looked a bit more like this:

> [image][image][image]

It is only alluding to the [Goldmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_gold_mark) which was in circulation before the war to inspire confidence. This notgeld was issued on September 27th, 1923, very shortly before the reforms that switched away from the inflated [Papiermark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Papiermark) and made the [Rentenmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Rentenmark) legal tender everywhere.

The Text on this specimen is somewhat hard to decipher.

> Pößnecker Tausch-Wert-Schein
>   Wert 1,50 Goldmark
>   Der ..... (Gemeindevorsteher?)   ____  Der Gemeinderat
>
> Der Geldschein ist nur Scheingeld
>   Das nicht mehr seinen Wert erhält
>   Doch Pößnecks Leder ihr achten sollt
>   Wie altes Geld von echtem Gold
>
> Vorm Kriege eine Mark ich galt
>   Doch schätzte hoch mich jung und alt
>   Mir wuchs danach ein Nullenschweif(?)
>   Fürs Irrenhaus die Welt ist reif
>
> Die deutsche Mark kam auf den Hund
>   Doch deutscher Mann ist noch gesund!
>   Was der an Werken täglich schafft
>   Der Börsenschwindel an sich rafft.
>
> Kaufst du 'ne Serie Sohlengeld,
>   Der Wucher nichts von dir erhält
>   Geschützt bist du ein ganzes Jahr
>   Vor Schnupfen und vor Reißen gar,
>   Denn diese Sohlen, zäh und dicht,
>   Die dulden kalte Füße nicht.
>
> Neptunia. Das beste Sohlenleder der Welt. Lederfabrik Diesel & Weise, Pößneck. Potthoff & Kayser, Blankenburg-Mark.

Rough translation:

> Paper money is just illusory, and cannot keep its value any longer, but leather from Pößneck you should accept, just like the money of old when it was backed by gold.
>
> Before the war I was worth one mark, and was in high regard by young and old, but then I grew a tail of nulls, now the world is ready for the madhouse.
>
> The Deutschmark has gone to the dogs, but the German man is still in good health! What he creates by hard days work, gets eaten by the swindle that is stock exchange.
>
> If you buy a series of Sohlengeld (the leather money), the usury gets nothing from you, you are protected for a full year, even from sniffling or ripping (~illness), because these soles, tough and tight, they do not tolerate cold feet.

Note the distinction between creative capital and snatching (raffling, speculative) capital, a potentially [antisemitic](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brechung_der_Zinsknechtschaft) criticism of capitalism, exemplified in the [25-Points programme of the NSDAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Socialist_Program), and making this little ensuring poem worthy of repetition in a nazi newspaper, years later:  [Litzmannstadter Zeitung 1941 kw IV Nr 311, p8.](http://bc.wimbp.lodz.pl/Content/28524/Litzmannstadter%20Zeitung%201941%20kw%20IV%20Nr%20311.pdf). This newspaper article also confirms that there was only a little run of 987 pieces.

Comment: @StarSapphire please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the tickmark next to it, if it solved your question.